# Python - While-Loop until list is empty

Tags: python

I'm working with Django and I have a queryset of objects that has been converted to a list (`unpaid_sales`). I'm executing a process that iterates through this list and operates on each item until either the list is empty, or a given integer (`bucket`) reaches zero.

This is how I set it up:

```
while unpaid_sales:
    while bucket > 0:
        unpaid_sale = unpaid_sales.pop(0)
        ...do stuff
```

In some cases, I am getting the following error:

> pop from empty list

What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Use a single while with `or`.

Comment: When does `bucket` change?

Comment: I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your end criteria must be formulated a little differently: run the loop while there are items and the `bucket` is positive. `or` is not the right operation here.

```
while unpaid_sales and bucket > 0:
    unpaid_sale = unpaid_sales.pop(0)
    #do stuff
```

Comment: They each have their own else conditions. Does `elif` work with `while` loops?

Comment: Not realy. But in this case you should probably use a normal if statement after the while loop

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Do not use separate `while`loops. Do as follows :

```
while unpaid_sales and bucket > 0 :
    unpaid_sale = unpaid_sales.pop(0)
    ...do stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

You should do a single loop: `while bucket>0 and unpaid_sales`. Here, you are popping elements in the `bucket` loop, and then just just check that `bucket` is positive, but you do not check that `element_sales` still has elements in it.